# Can't pass arguments to singleton function in xcode

Tags: iphone, xcode, function, singleton, arguments

I have a **singleton** in application and need to call its function with arguements from another class, but when I call it, nil arguements are passed...here is the code:

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    NSLog([Singleton sharedMySingleton].test);
    NSDictionary *story = [self.filters objectAtIndex: indexPath.row];

    MainAppRecord *record = [[[MainAppRecord alloc]init]retain];
    record.name = [story objectForKey:@"Name"];
    record.searchUrl = [story objectForKey:@"SearchUrl"];
    record.icon = [imageCash objectForKey:indexPath];
    [[Singleton sharedMySingleton] changeMainFilterTo:record atPosition:indexOfFilterToChange];
```

}

Here is Singleton.h and its function:

```
@interface Singleton : NSObject {

    NSMutableArray *mainFilters;
    NSString *test;
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSMutableArray *mainFilters;
@property (nonatomic, retain) MainAppRecord *filterToChange;

-(void) initWithPlist;
-(void) saveToPlist;
-(void)changeMainFilterTo:(MainAppRecord*)record atPosition:(int)position;
+(Singleton *)sharedMySingleton;

@end



-(void)changeMainFilterTo:(MainAppRecord*)record atPosition:(int)position 
{
    [mainFilters insertObject:record atIndex:position];
}
```

The app crashes with

2012-10-20 16:24:52.789 TableView[1957:207] -[__NSArrayI insertObject:atIndex:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x68410f0

Thanks

Comment: What makes you believe that no arguments are passed?  Have you tried putting in some NSLog() statements to verify what is sent and received?  (Also, there's usually no reason to have an extra `retain` after an `alloc` since it already gets you a retained object.)

Comment: debugging. Shows a nil argument passed

Comment: Ah...passing `nil` and not being able to pass any arguments are different concepts.  I'd try putting a breakpoint on the call to `changeMainFilterTo:` and examining the value of `record`, then stepping into the method.

Comment: Please be more specific, from your comments below it is hard to tell what is going on. Set a breakpoint at didSelectRow and follow the code through. Does `record` get created properly? At what specific point does it crash? Which variable is nil? Are you using ARC anywhere (perhaps in the singleton only)? Why aren't you using the variable that is passed in in the method in the singleton?

Comment: Phillip, I've done very that thing...I'm a bit surprised, but when changed the array to mutable copy, everything came fine, argument too...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is nothing to do with arguments not being passed, or singletons.

You've declared an NSMutableArray property in your singleton, but it looks like you've assigned an NSArray to it. You don't show where you set this up but it looks like you're loading it from a property list - this creates a immutable array by default. You then try to insert an object - which up can't do to an immutable array.

Ensure that when you create the array, you are creating a mutable array.

The simplest way to do this is to find the code where you are currently assigning the array, and make a mutable copy instead:

```
self.mainFilters = [[NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithData:other] mutableCopy];
```

Comment: Unfortunately its not the problem. The function works properly with array when I create manually an argument. The issue still is in passing the arguement from another class. While debugging function argument is nil when singleton is called from another class. I suppose it is connected somehow to memory management but I can't figure out exactly wht it is

Comment: What is nil, anyway? In the code above you aren't even _using_ the argument that you pass in.

Comment: it isn't crashing when I manually call it inside init function of singleton. Still crashing when i try to reach it from another class.

Comment: that was the edition issue...it is not working with argument.

Comment: Its a bit funny but it works now with mutable copy =| I'm confused why it worked differently in different situations, but MutableCopy does the full job...   Thanks a lot for patience!

Comment: I think you missed to property the nsstring test in the header.